# How to refactor 2000 lines of simple bool?

Tags: pine-script

for PineScript,

how to refactor this?

```
f_function() =>
    h1 = close > close[1]
    h2 = close > close[2]
    h3 = close > close[3]
    ...
    h1998 = close > close[1998]
    h1999 = close > close[1999]
    h2000 = close > close[2000]
    _return = h1 and h2 and h3 and ... and h1998 and h1999 and h2000
```

had tried
for loop
but results don't produce quite the same

GOAL
thing is, I have another bool expression like this

impulse = expression1 and expression2 and f_function()

so the
f_function()
is being called each time for each bar...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to figure out if the current candle's close value is the highest amongst the last 2000 bars.

You can use the built-in function `ta.highest()` for that.

```
is_highest = ta.highest(close, 2000)
```

## Edit

To make it a `bool` you can do the following:

```
is_highest = close == ta.highest(close, 2000)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Correct, but I have another bool expression that calls the f_function() again n again for each bar

PS: have edited thread above with extra details

Comment: Please see my edit. It will give a `bool` result which you can use.

Comment: yes, but then I have to make it

ta.highest(close, 2000) and ta.highest(close, 1999) and ta.highest(close, 1998) and ta.highest(close, 1997)...

Comment: Why? If `ta.highest(close, 2000)` true, `ta.highest(close, 1999)` will be true too. Why do you need to check for that?

Comment: you're right. I've been overthinking it all along! Always helps to see things visually on chart. So my solution is ( close > ta.highest(close,2000)[1] ) for the entire 2000 lines refactoring...